# Since I can buy a remote shutter release for my Fujifilm Finepix, why can't I also tether?

Tags: fujifilm, tethering, intervalometer

After reading a lot of information, it appears that it is not possible to tether capture with most Fujifilm Finepix cameras.
However, I have bought this device on Amazon and it allows me to remote capture:
http://www.amazon.co.uk/Maxsimafoto-compatible-shutter-release-Fujifilm/dp/B004ZV646O

Wouldn't it be possible to send the same signal to the usb that this device sends? So I could programme it in my laptop for the time interval that I wish?

Thanks.

Comment: There is a difference between tethered capture and shutter release.

> Tethered shooting is connecting a computer to the camera when you shoot so the pictures you take a downloaded to the computer rather than (or in addition) to a memory card.

Source: http://www.diyphotography.net/introduction-tethered-shooting/

The device you have bought, is a shutter release. It does nothing else but release the shutter without having to put your finger on the camera's shutter button.

We cannot provide you with a correct answer to your question unless you also tell what camera model exactly you have.

Answer (score 1):

Tethered shooting can mean a couple of different things, but usually it would  involve sending the images back to a remote display system. From that remote display you can see a live picture as though it was an extension of the camera's viewfinder and then when you shoot it also has the capability of storing the shot in that remote device. This would require much more bandwidth and technology.

Some people use it (perhaps not quite correctly) when referring only to remote triggering.

The remote trigger you pointed us to is about as basic as they get. I found a [more sophisticated remote switch for your camera](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00310WIII) which allows you to set a timer for delayed shots or intervals for timelapse photography. Theoretically, it would be possible to duplicate this sort of behaviour from a laptop or other device, but this is still far simpler than the technology that you would need to stream images back to the device from the camera, which probably explains why you are having difficulty finding anything if you are searching for any sort of "tethering".

One possible solution for your camera, if you really are concerned about seeing the image remotely, would be a combination of one of those remote triggers with an Eye-Fi SD card in your camera to allow you to stream your images back to another wifi enabled computer or device.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I understand what you tell me about the difference between tethering and remote trigering, my question was about finding a way of duplicating this behaviour with my laptop to not have to buy that 40€ remote control. But maybe is not worthy at all.